# Excel VBA Listbox showing previous record after new selection is made

Tags: forms, excel, listbox, vba

So I have listbox1 on a user form.  When a user clicks an item in the list box I have the value of the list box selection populate cell C20 on a worksheet.

```
Private Sub frmListBox1_Click()
Worksheets("CONTROLSRFDS").Range("C20").Value = frmListBox1.Value

For i = 1 To 53 ' Non Multipage Controls
    Me.Controls("Label" & i).Caption = Worksheets("CONTROLSRFDS").Range("RBSLabels").Cells(i, 1).Value
    Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value = Worksheets("CONTROLSRFDS").Range("RBSOutput").Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i

End Sub
```

Based on the selection now in cell C20, the worksheet will re-calculate over 30 ranges of data with formulas that are based on this one value in cell C20.
These 30 ranges of data are coded to transfer their new values onto the label captions that are contained on the user form.

What's happening is that the form will initialize correctly, BUT once the list box is selected for a new selection, all the values on the user form show values that belong to the previous selection, however on the worksheet the formulas are calculating correctly, it's just that the new values are not populating the label captions on the user form with the right information.  I've beat  myself  up trying to figure this out by using change events and click events in the worksheet module and in the form itself with no success.  I can't get this solved. At each click the data displayed is showing the previous record.

Code for the ListBox Change Event:

```
Private Sub frmListBox1_Change()

If Application.CalculationState = done Then

Worksheets("CONTROLSRFDS").Range("C20").Value = frmListBox1.Value

For i = 1 To 53 ' Non Multipage Controls
Me.Controls("Label" & i).Caption = Worksheets("CONTROLSRFDS").Range("RBSLabels").Cells(i, 1).Value
Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value = Worksheets("CONTROLSRFDS").Range("RBSOutput").Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i

ii = 1 'Antenna Labels
For i = 54 To 75
Me.Controls("Label" & i).Caption = Worksheets("CONTROLSRFDS").Range("AntennaLabels").Cells(ii, 1).Value
        ii = ii + 1
Next i
End If
End sub
```

Can someone please help with this??  What am doing wrong? Is there a index property I'm not referencing?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Solved.  Inserted the below code into the click event of the listbox prior to running all the procedure:

```
Application.Calculate
If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
    DoEvents
End If
```

Thank you to all who made the effort to view my post.

Happy New year.